# IIS Application: Remote Server DHCP IP Reservation with Netsh

Tags: asp.net, powershell, iis, ip, dhcp

Today I confront a problem while staging project to live servers. Shortly product working on IIS 7 Server 2008 r2. It's main purpose is multiple DHCP IP reservation to remote servers at same time. There is no problem when I develop project on 2 test servers. I can reservate IP's from one to another remotely. But today same configurations does not work for live server. I will use these server names for scenario: Local, Test, Live

Asp. net codes working on Local server. It can reservate IP's on itself and Test. But when I try to do same things on Live server netsh script output gives me "The command needs a valid Scope IP Address." error.I am sure there is no problem at command string. I used few methods to solve problems:

- Appropriate netsh command written to powershell then run that ps1 on
  code with runspace environment.
- Try to run with C# diagnostic Process .bat or .ps1 script.
- I wrote helper Python script to run netsh command, so I could detect
  if there is a problem on codebehind privilages or IIS problem. But
  not helped.

But most important thing, **I can do reservations with manual clicking on Local server.** It is working succesfully on Live server. At this point I cant understand source of problem. Also I did some some authorization and privilages config on both servers:

- Set-ExecutionPolicy unrestriced (That is not even remotesigned)
- I gave full permission to user on live server
- DefaultAppPool settings done. I checked file permissions.

What can be differences of Live and Test servers? Why I can not do reservations with code on Live server? I am looking for your answers. Thanks in advances, have a nice day!

Comment: You might want to check if Active Directory is in use and that the AD Account you are using has the correct privileges. You might also want to check the DNS and any firewalls.

Comment: I found something about privilages. I thought "runas" verb enough for elevated termination. But when I try to run cmd with admin manually everything is fine. But without, netsh command gives  "The command needs a valid Scope IP Address.". I do not understand why "StartInfo.Verb = "runas"; " does not work. By the way server UAC is disabled on server. Any clue?

Comment: this is a little outside my realm, but the UAC is the User Account Control and this is often required to allow access to certain areas of the system even though it can be a pain sometimes. for netsh this link might be helpful https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490941.aspx You might want to find the administrator of your servers and have a chat with them on how security is working for your network.